# LWC: How do I display "out of box" object hover?

Tags: lightning-web-components

When you hover over an Account name link on standard views, a popup with the Compact Layout shows the details of that record.
[image]
Is it possible to do this using Lightning Web Components?

Perhaps using the output from `getRecordUi`?  I cannot find any examples online of how to use the results from getRecordUi - how can that be converted to a page layout to display to the user?

---

*Some related links that I found, but did not have answers:*

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_record_ui

https://rajvakati.com/2019/01/28/getrecordui-wire-adapter/

[I have lightning component and want to show lightning card when mouse over on the link,](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174225/i-have-lightning-component-and-want-to-show-lightning-card-when-mouse-over-on-th)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can build a custom lwc in which you embed some sort of 'popover' overlay component. So yes, this is possible.

If your Layout is, for example, a Table, as follows:

```
<template>

<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Name">Name</div>
            </th>
            <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Age">Age</div>
            </th>
            <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Birthday">Birthday</div>
            </th>
            <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Height">Height</div>
            </th>
            <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Sex">Sex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Weight">Weight</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <template if:true={bears.data}>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <template  for:each={bears.data} for:item="bear" for:index="index">

                <tr class={assignClass} key={bear.Id} data-rangerid={bear.Supervisor__c} onmouseout={hideData} onmouseover={showData}>

                    <td data-label="Bear Name" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                        <div class=slds-truncate title="Bear Name">{bear.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Bear Age" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Age">{bear.Age__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Bear Birthday" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Birthday">{bear.Birthday__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Bear Height" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Height">{bear.Height__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Bear Sex" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Sex">{bear.Sex__c}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Bear Weight" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Weight">{bear.Weight__c}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                </template>
            </div>
    </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

you can "Build" a LWC that will act as a popover (a card for example, with an embeded [lightning-record-view-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-view-form/documentation).

this is a sample lwc that I added at the bottom of my table:

`<c-box-popover topmargin={top} leftmarginn={left} myranger={ranger}></c-box-popover>`

it basically receives coordinates of where my cursor is located (you can do this as well in the child lwc).

my table component in return has uses `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events for rendering/unrendering the card based on the `id` that is being passed to it.

Example:

```
showData(event){
    this.ranger = event.currentTarget.dataset.rangerid;
    this.left = event.clientX;
    this.top=event.clientY;
}
hideData(event){
    this.ranger = "";
}
```

My popover in returns, simply passes the id attribute aka, `myranger` to the record-view-form component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <template if:true={ranger} >
        <lightning-record-view-form
                record-id={ranger}
                object-api-name="Contact">
            <div class="potato slds-box" style={boxClass}>
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Name">
                </lightning-output-field>
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Email">
                </lightning-output-field>
                </div>
        </lightning-record-view-form>
    </template>
</div>
```

and as you can see, I dynamically assign a "style" attribute which I construct using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
get boxClass() { 
    return `background-color:white; top:${this.top - 280}px; left:${this.left}px`;
  }
```

I did not put much effort in calculating screensize to properly place the popover, but it should give you the general idea.

[image][image]

You can find a sample [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/gminero/cc99462da94c1f465ef75218a2cde078)

The data i used ot work with can be found on the [build-apps-with-lwc Trailhead repository](https://github.com/trailheadapps/build-apps-with-lwc)

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `lightning:overlayLibrary` which does not currently have an LWC equivalent. Specifically, this is the `popover` functionality.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation

Unfortunately, there is no official word on when this aura service component will move to LWC.