# Popup on mouse hover for LWC datatable

Tags: lightning-datatable

I am working on converting VF component to LWC. I use lightning out to display LWC on VF page. The data I get is the Id of lookup fields (account and user). I want to display it as it is displayed in VF component. The VF component shows name and also shows details on mouse hover. Can this be done for LWC datatable?

**VF and it's corresponding LWC**

[image: components]

**Pop Up on Mouse Hover**

[image: popup]

**Data received by VF component and LWC**

[image: data]

**HTML**

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Visit Report" icon-name="standard:catalog">
        <div class="slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-scrollable slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns} key-field="id"  
                hide-checkbox-column="true" 
                onrowaction={handleRowActions}></lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**Javascript**

```js
const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Action',
        initialWidth: 50,
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'View',
            name: 'view',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    },
    { label: 'Engagement Report', fieldName: 'Name', type:'text' }, 
    {
        label: 'Account',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {fieldName: 'Account__c'},
            name: 'account',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    },
    { label: 'Visit/Report Date', fieldName: 'Visit_Date__c', type: 'date',
        typeAttributes: {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            year: 'numeric',
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: true
        },
    }, 
    { label: 'Format Type', fieldName: 'Visit_Type__c', type: 'text' }, 
    { label: 'Temperature Reading', fieldName: 'Temperature_Reading__c', type: 'text' }, 
    { label: 'Send Copy to Editorial Team', fieldName: 'Send_copy_to_Editorial_team__c', type: 'text' }, 
    {
        label: 'Created By ID',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {fieldName: 'CreatedById'},
            name: 'createdBy',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Last Modified By ID',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {fieldName: 'LastModifiedById'},
            name: 'modifiedBy',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    }, 
];

export default class RelatedVisitReport extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track data;
    @track error;
    @track columns = columns;

    @wire(visitReport, { contactId: '$recordId' }) wired(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.data = result.data;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }
    //code to handle row actions of datatable
}
```

Comment: You have to create a custom component -  Similar question was asked before https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257221/lwc-how-do-i-display-out-of-box-object-hover

Comment: @Amit Thanks! Can you help me with LWC datatable displaying ID instead of Name as displayed in VF datatable?

Comment: Are you want to display name instead of Id in lwc?

Comment: @Amit Yes I want to display Name instead of ID in my LWC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing popup use custom component - [LWC: How do I display "out of box" object hover?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257221/lwc-how-do-i-display-out-of-box-object-hover)

For showing hyperlink use typeAttribute in lightning-datatable. Use following updated code snippet.

```
const columns = [
    {
        label: 'Action',
        initialWidth: 50,
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: 'View',
            name: 'view',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    },
    { label: 'Engagement Report', fieldName: 'Name', type:'text' }, 
    //For Hyperlink
    {
        label: 'Account',
        fieldName: 'AccountLink',
        type: 'url',
        typeAttributes:
        {
            label: {
                fieldName: 'AccountName'
            }
        }
    },
    //End For Hyperlink
    { label: 'Visit/Report Date', fieldName: 'Visit_Date__c', type: 'date',
        typeAttributes: {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: '2-digit',
            year: 'numeric',
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: true
        },
    }, 
    { label: 'Format Type', fieldName: 'Visit_Type__c', type: 'text' }, 
    { label: 'Temperature Reading', fieldName: 'Temperature_Reading__c', type: 'text' }, 
    { label: 'Send Copy to Editorial Team', fieldName: 'Send_copy_to_Editorial_team__c', type: 'text' }, 
    {
        label: 'Created By ID',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {fieldName: 'CreatedById'},
            name: 'createdBy',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Last Modified By ID',
        type: 'button',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: {fieldName: 'LastModifiedById'},
            name: 'modifiedBy',
            variant: 'base',
        }
    }, 
];

export default class RelatedVisitReport extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track data;
    @track error;
    @track columns = columns;

    @wire(visitReport, { contactId: '$recordId' }) wired(result) {
        //Clone returned Array
        let  newArray = result.data.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
        if (result.data) {
            let  newArray = result.data.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
                for(let i=0; i< newArray.length; i++) {
                    newArray[i].AccountLink = "/"+newArray[i].Account__c;
                    newArray[i].AccountName = "/"+newArray[i].Account__r.Name; // Query Account__r.Name field
            }
            this.data = newArray;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }
    //code to handle row actions of datatable
}
```

Comment: Can I trigger `onRowAction` using column type `url` for lightning datatable?