# How to create custom related list quick links in lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lwc-wire-adapter

I am trying to create a custom related list quick link inside a LWC. I have 2 objects A and B.  From the apex I am returning the list of B related record but how can I display it like a related list quick link on LWC? Any idead how to do this? Please help on this.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? where did you get stuck?

Comment: i am fetching all list and storing in a data table. But not sure how to implement related list quick link kind of look

Comment: to confirm, you want it to be an icon that when you hover over it will show a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out this solution here:

[LWC: How do I display "out of box" object hover?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257221/lwc-how-do-i-display-out-of-box-object-hover)

It looks like they were able to create a hover link with a compact layout - you could piggy back off of this design and on hover display a Lightning Table.

I would look here for information on the data table: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example