# display all the row data on mouse hover event

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-datatable, lightning-web-components, datatables.js

I have created a data table in LWC that contains lots of data in a row that can not be displayed in that row. So I'm trying to display whole row data on mouse hover. If anyone has implemented this before, please help me with this.
[image]

Comment: Please refer to this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257221/lwc-how-do-i-display-out-of-box-object-hover

Comment: Thanks Samir, I still have a question. As you can see in the third and fourth column '...' at the end, that means there is more data in that column. so I just want to display that data by increasing the row height or width OR using a pop-up.