# How to add popovers on dueling picklist in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, popover

I need to add popovers to dueling picklist, but I am not able to find any examples online.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [design system blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/dueling-picklist/) as a starter. You will still need to implement all the JS logic, as per the popover, you can simply calculate your pointers position to display a popover.

[This Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257221/lwc-how-do-i-display-out-of-box-object-hover/257253#257253), has details on displaying a popover in lwc for a different use case, but the principle is the same.